# Custom X & Y -axis labels for the Primefaces charts

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have p:barchart graph in my application and I use Primefaces version3.2 with JSF2.

My question is how can I customize the labels on my Y-axis.
Chart is picking values from my model for labels on the axis. Instead I need to customize the labels like 3K instead of 3000 etc.